# How to change the font of the qcombobox label/header only?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

When I change the font of my QComboBox `comboBox->setFont(whateverQFont);` it is applied on the dropdown menu as well (all the items), and it overrides the Qt::FontRole data I have set on my items with `comboBox->setItemData(index, itemSpecificFont, Qt::FontRole);`

I'd like to set a font on the QComboBox label only and leave the dropdown displayed as it was. Or even better : to have directly the same font as the selected item.
Is there an easy way to do that ?

**Edit:** Solution of *Jasonhan* works fine for an editable QComboBox (-> setting the font on the QLineEdit) but is not applicable for a regular QComboBox, as the QLabel is private.

Comment: I've been able to achieve what I want in the paint function, by retrieving the currentData-fontRole and applying the font to the painter. Though it requires to copy/paste the QComboBox paint code to modify it in a subclass... If anyone has a more clean and simple way to get around my issue, let me know !

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but why can't you use CSS https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox ?

Comment: @agilob I want the label part of the combobox to display the same style as the selected item, so it depends on the item. The item is style is defined by code, I don't see any way to propagate it to the cbb-label using CSS.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion because the docs say that only editable QComboboxes have a QLineEdit. It might be better to say that only editable QComboxes are given a QLineEdit by default. You can supply your own QLineEdit to *any* QCombobox, using `void QComboBox::setLineEdit(QLineEdit *edit)`, and from there do whatever you like, include over-riding the paint event or setting the text or the font. You can do pretty much anything this way.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 years, I saw this question. I don't know whether you have found a better method or not. If not, following code may give you a hint.

`QComboBox` label as you said is actually a `QLineEdit`, so you just need to set this component's font, and it will solve your problem.

```
QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();
//add some list items to box
if (box->lineEdit())
    box->lineEdit()->setFont(font);//font is your desirable font
```

Comment: Smart, but as the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#lineEdit) says *Only editable combo boxes have a line edit.*. Then your solution leads to a crash for a simple QComboBox.

Comment: `if (box->lineEdit())` will guarantee that your code will not crash.

Comment: But it will also not work... So that's not a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But another way may do a trick. If you make the first item in the list occupy the position of the label, than it looks like the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something that works for a non-editable QComboBox is to install a QProxyStyle that sets the font when a CE_ComboBoxLabel control element is drawn.

Here's an example that sets the label font to italic:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProxyStyle>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QComboBox>

class MyProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    void drawControl(QStyle::ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option,
                     QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget = nullptr) const override
    {
        if (element == QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel)
        {
            auto fnt = painter->font();
            fnt.setItalic(true);
            painter->setFont(fnt);
        }
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setStyle(new MyProxyStyle);

    QComboBox cb;
    cb.addItem("Option 1");
    cb.addItem("Option 2");
    cb.addItem("Option 3");
    cb.show();

    app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting implement a custom model you could try with QListView. 
It just applies to the drop-down menu and you can change its font with the usual *setFont* function; the you have to apply it to your QComboBox thorugh routine *setView*.

Something like this (it's not Qt C++ code, I've skipped all arguments in function calls):

```
QComboBox *combobox = new QComboBox();
combobox->setFont();
...
QListView *listview = new QListView();
listview->setFont();

combobox->setView(listview);
```

Comment: My problem is I have different fonts in the listview, and the default one is dealing well with that. I just want to apply the selected-item font to the combobox-label part, that would be more a change of the label view object than the listview object (but it's not accessible outside of the QComboBox class).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misunderstood your question. You can use QComboBox signal 'currentIndexChanged(int index)', connect it with your custom slot in which you use the index of the selected item (passed as argument) to retrieve font information with function 'itemData(...)' and the apply font to QComboBox, so that drop down menu fonts remain the same but the combobox label font is changed according to the selected item

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried this but it does not work because the listview (child of the combobox) uses the font applied to the QComboBox for all the items.